# How to activate spring profile properly in web application

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to configure two different configuration classes in my web application -- one that uses jdbc and another that uses hibernate.I defined my configuration classes as below:

```
@Profile("jdbc")
@Configuration
public class JdbcConfiguration {
  ...
}


@Profile("hibernate")
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfiguration {
   ...
}
```

I have two more main configuration classes.One is for services and one that defines some database infrastructure needed by both jdbc and hibernate configuration classes(for example,the data source bean).Here are the classes:

```
@Import({JdbcConfiguration.class, HibernateConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:/db.properties")
public class DataAccessConfiguration {
   ...
}



@Configuration
@Import(DataAccessConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"domain.validation","services"})
public class ServiceConfiguration {

    private final UserDao userDao;

    private final GroupDao groupDao;

    private final TaskDao taskDao;

    public ServiceConfiguration(UserDao userDao, GroupDao groupDao, TaskDao taskDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
        this.groupDao = groupDao;
        this.taskDao = taskDao;
    }
    ...
}
```

The thing i am trying to do is that the DataAccessConfiguration imports both jdbc and hibernate configuration.If jdbc profile is active,then only the beans in jdbc configuration should be created.Otherwise(if hibernate profile is active),hibernate's beans should be created.Then i import DataAccessConfig into ServiceConfiguration,which uses dao beans in the services.
I read in documentation that in order to activate a profile in web application,i need to define context parameter spring.profiles.active in my web.xml or add it programmatically to servletContext on boot.I did the former.Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app metadata-complete="false" version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" >
  <display-name>Easy Do Web</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc</param-value>
  </context-param>


</web-app>
```

I am not sure if this is important,but i configure my servletdispatcher by extending AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer .

The error that i am getting when i try to start my application is :

```
02-Jan-2020 13:29:46.070 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
02-Jan-2020 13:29:48.973 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [listeners.ContListener]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.UserDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:400)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:732)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:89)
        at listeners.ContListener.contextInitialized(ContListener.java:37)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1728)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.UserDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1695)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778)
        ... 69 more
02-Jan-2020 13:29:48.974 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
02-Jan-2020 13:29:52.700 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Here is full jdbc configuration class(Same three dao beans are defined in hibernate configuration,except the classes are different):

```
@Profile("jdbc")
@Configuration
public class JdbcConfiguration {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public JdbcConfiguration(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "userDao")
    public UserDao userDao(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template){
        return new UserDaoSpringJdbc(dataSource,template);
    }

    @Bean(name = "groupDao")
    public GroupDao groupDao(UserDao userDao,NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template){
        return new GroupDaoSpringJdbc(dataSource,userDao,template);
    }

    @Bean(name="taskDao")
    public TaskDao taskDao(UserDao userDao,GroupDao groupDao,NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template){
        return new TaskDaoSpringJdbc(dataSource,userDao,groupDao,template);
    }

    @Bean
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager jdbcTransactionManager() {
        DataSourceTransactionManager manager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        manager.setDataSource(dataSource);

        return manager;
    }



}
```

Comment: Try to change the position of 
@Configuration@Profile("jdbc")public class.....

Comment: What is the purpose of the `@Import` annotations?  Surely each configuration should be detected independently

Comment: Can you post your UserDao class also since stack trace says that no userDoa bean created in the spring context

Comment: This is a very fascinating question. I never heard of someone switching from JDBC to Hibernate through profiles. I realise I'm not providing any answer but... what are you planning to use this setup for? What is this approach giving you?

Comment: @AndyN according to documentation:...Provides functionality equivalent to the <import/> element in Spring XML....

Comment: @FilippoPossenti I'd say the reason is completely "educational". Currently i am using dao layer implemented through spring jdbc support(jdbc template).In the future i'd like to switch to hibernate(keeping both implementations).

Comment: can you test this using  active profile as jdbc ?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine even though we don't need @imported as it is very similar to  in xml way of bean configuration.

According to stack trace,
repository.UserDao bean is not created in the spring context.

There is no UserDao bean defined in spring context to do so.
Solution is to create/register userDao bean in the spring context  by annotating 
the UserDao class with @Repository .

Comment: I have defined three bean definitions in both -- jdbc and hibernate -- configuration classes.I added full code of jdbc configuration class to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used XML Configuration or Annotations? If you have Spring 4.0 Annotations, then you need to Autowire DAO Components.One more thing you need to keep in mind is
that Component Scan should include all the DAO Components you have scanned, otherwise, even though you may use Autowired, Still scanner won't be able to locate it in Scanning packages which you can define in XML or through Annotations.

Answer (score 0):

The error was fixed.It was my assumption wrong,because i thought that spring would activate profile before my configuration class is created,but,apparently,spring activates the profile only when loading the already created configuration class to create the web application context.What i did was : i removed the import and added the two(jdbc and hibernate) configuration classes to be loaded with the service configuration class,thus spring loads jdbc and hibernate first and then the service.Hope this helps someone.